# Angular and yarn workspace : missing file at TS compilation time

Tags: angular, typescript, yarn-workspaces

Context: I'm using yarn workspace with a custom webpack/angular 5 conf for a while. I'm trying to use ng cli tool with angular 8. But a weird issue appears.

First, here is the error:

> ERROR in ../node_modules/@project/messages/src/index.ts
>   Module build failed (from ../node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
>   Error: /path/to/right/folder/node_modules/@project/messages/src/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>   The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format ([goo.gl/jB3GVv](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview)).
>
> [Insert here terrible not humanly understandable stack trace]

I assume the problem is the symlink that yarn is creating. Here is my folder architecture.

```
.
├── libs
│   ├── messages
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   ├── LICENSE
│       ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── physics
│       ├── jest.config.js
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── node_modules
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── LICENSE
├── game
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── browserslist
│   ├── e2e
│   ├── karma.conf.js
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.spec.json
│   ├── tslint.json
│   └── yarn.lock
├── node_modules
│   ├── @project
│   └── some other packages (mb like over 99999999, but nvm)
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── server
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── main.ts
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

And also symlink mapping:

```
ls -la node_modules/@project 
total 40
drwxrwxr-x   2 nek nek  4096 juin  24 23:24 .
drwxrwxr-x 912 nek nek 36864 juin  24 23:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nek nek    14 juin  24 23:24 client -> ../../game
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nek nek    19 juin  24 23:24 messages -> ../../libs/messages
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nek nek    18 juin  24 23:24 physics -> ../../libs/physics
lrwxrwxrwx   1 nek nek    22 juin  24 23:24 server -> ../../server
```

Nothing looks so wrong. But at build time it fails. I can't understand why. But check out this output of `ng --version`:

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.0.4
Node: 10.16.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: <error>
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       <error>
@angular-devkit/build-angular   <error>
@angular-devkit/core            <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics      <error>
@schematics/angular             <error>
@schematics/update              <error>
rxjs                            <error>
typescript                      <error>
```

It looks somehow like this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3864#issuecomment-303168778 but I don't have the same problem (considering the location of node_modules is accurate in my case).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started a new project with npm/lerna (should work just like yarn workspaces). And had same issue. But solved it.

The problem was the configuration of TypeScript (in tsconfig.json file). I set the `path` configuration of my tsconfig:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
        "@project/physics": ["../libs/physics"]
     }
 }
```

Working like a charm.